# ASP.NET Core - Post requests using [HttpPost] not working for objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to do a simple POST request but it seems like `[FromBody]` cannot seem to understand more than 2 parameters.

The request:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IEnumerable<EnergyMarket> addEnergy([FromBody] EnergyMarket energyMarket)
 {
     _energyMarketService.addEnergy(energyMarket.Name, energyMarket.StockIPO, energyMarket.EnergyPrice);
     return _energyMarketService.Energies;
 }
```

The object:

```
public class EnergyMarket
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("stockipo")]
    public string StockIPO { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public double EnergyPrice { get; set; }

    public EnergyMarket() { }

    public EnergyMarket(string name, string stockIPO, double val)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.StockIPO = stockIPO;
        this.EnergyPrice = val;
    }
}
```

Request (Content-type is application/json)

```
{
   "name": "Air Canada",
   "stockipo": "AC.TO",
   "price": 13.12
}
```

When I go on POSTMAN and put the following request, it works fine for the first two parameters, but the `price` is always 0. When I changed the price from a double to string, the string was always null.

Comment: asp.net core model binder has nothing to do with newtonsoft json attributes. field should be called `energyPrice`

Comment: oh man, such a rookie mistake! it works well now. thank you :) @YegorAndrosov

Comment: I posted solution how to do it without changing your attributes or renaming properties. just fyi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default ASP.NET Core model binder does not use Newtonsoft.Json property attributes. Therefore, we should implement it ourselves.

Firstly, create implementation of `IModelBinder` that would read request body and deserialize it using Newtonsoft `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method

```
public class NewtonsoftModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        string valueFromBody = string.Empty;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            valueFromBody = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueFromBody))
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(valueFromBody, bindingContext.ModelType);

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        }
        catch
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                "", "Model can not be deserialized.");

        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Then there are multiple ways how we can apply it to our code, but the easiest one is to put it as attribute on your `EnergyMarket` class

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(NewtonsoftModelBinder))]
public class EnergyMarket
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("stockipo")]
    public string StockIPO { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public double EnergyPrice { get; set; }

    public EnergyMarket() { }

    public EnergyMarket(string name, string stockIPO, double val)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.StockIPO = stockIPO;
        this.EnergyPrice = val;
    }
}
```

Finally, we can see correct data in controller after Postman request

[image]
[image]